# Matrix Inverse of Outer Product of a vector with itself

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Suppose I have a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and the matrix
$$
A = \lambda x x^\top \qquad\lambda \in \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}
$$
I would like to find an expression for its inverse. Is there a simple expression?

Comment: All I know for now is that $(xx^\top)^{\frac{1}{2}} = xx^\top$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you've defined the matrix, you essentially have the SVD for free.

Therefore calculating the pseudoinverse is simple
$$\eqalign{
u &= \frac{x}{\|x||} \qquad
 &\big({\rm unit\,vector}\big) \\
A &= \lambda xx^T = \lambda\|x\|^2 uu^T = \sigma uu^T \quad
 &\big({\rm SVD}\big) \\
A^+ &= \frac{uu^T}{\sigma} = \frac{xx^T}{\sigma\|x\|^2} = \frac{xx^T}{\lambda\|x\|^4}
 &\big({\rm pseudoinverse}\big) \\
AA^+ &= \frac{(\lambda xx^T)xx^T}{\lambda\|x\|^4} = \frac{xx^T}{\|x\|^2} \\
}$$
Since $AA^+\ne I$ this is obviously ***not*** the regular matrix inverse, but it's the best you can do.

Answer (score 3):

If $n\neq 1$, then there is no solution since $A$ has rank at most $1$, whereas invertible matrices have rank $n$. When $n=1$, it is clear what the inverse is.

Comment: This is the typical form of a covariance matrix, which are invertible. Why would the rank be 1?